# How to check if an executor is running in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

is there a way to check in Jenkins pipeline if an executor is already running a job?
I would like to use different environment variables based on this condition.
The pseudo code of the pipeline I want is as following

IF
    Build of Job-A is triggered
THEN
    Use Environment_Variable_1
    USE Executor-1 for Job-A
ELSE IF
    JOB-A is running on Executor-1 AND Build of JOB-A is triggered again
THEN
    Use Environment_Variable_2
    USE Executor-2 for Job-A

The environment variable will hold paths to different folders because the Job is going to make changes to the folder. So when the Job is triggered again on executor 2, then I would like it to change the other folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way to check in Jenkins pipeline if an executor is already running a job?

Yes. With `jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.nodes` you can get all configured nodes. From those nodes you can get `Computer` objects with `node.toComputer()`. From `Computer` object it is possible to retrieve all `Executors` on that computer.

```
for (node in jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.nodes) {
  def computer = node.toComputer()   /* computer behind the node */
  def executors = computer.getExecutors()
  for (executor in executors) {
    println("Node name: " + node.getDisplayName())
    println("Computer name: " + computer.getDisplayName())
    println("Executor name: " + executor.getDisplayName())
    println("Executor number: " + executor.getNumber())
    println("Is executor busy: " + executor.isBusy())
  }
}
```

Documentation Jenkins Core API:
[Class Node](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Node.html)
[Class Computer](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/index-core.html)
[Class Executor](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Executor.html)

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for. I will read the documentation further to figure out if there is a way to check which job is running on the executor.

Comment: Can this be implemented in the pipeline script directly?

Comment: I have implemented it in a stage of the pipeline and it worked for me. If it doesn' t work for you, you could implement it in a function outside of the pipeline and call the function within a stage.

Comment: Is it possible to find on which Executor the job is running. Is the Job being executed by Executor 1 or Executor 2?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using nodes/agents, you could list the executors with this:

```
for( Computer c : Jenkins.getInstance().getComputers() ) {
  for (Executor e : c.getOneOffExecutors()) {
    println e
    println "Is executor busy: " + e.isBusy())
  }
}
```